# Converting data from exponential model to a linear model

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation

This question came up recently and I am really struggling to understand how to even do this. I have just started learning statistics and would like is someone could show me how this could be done in R.

Daily new infections of a virus seem to increase exponentially with time, implying a relationship

y = Ae^βx

where x is the date, and y is the number of new infections. Using a log transformation changes the model to:

log (y) = log (A) + βx

which is now a linear model. Compute the confidence interval for the parameter β.

What am I supposed to do here exactly? Am I suppposed to transfrom the data first and then run an lm() function to create a model? I am really confused please help!

Comment: Try `lm(log(y) ~ x)` the resulting coefficients will be beta and log(A).

Comment: I tried this but the problem is there are 0 values in the y data meaning I cant even find the log of y without creating an error

Comment: Since your model $e^x$ is always >0, it won't fit your y=0 values.  So you will either need a new model or figure out a way to deal with the zeros.  Maybe add a offset?

Comment: If your data are counts, you'd generally be better with a log-link model for counts -  a glm or related model (e.g. Poisson regression, negative binomial regression)